# Load libc.so.7 library on freebsd from Mono

Tags: mono, freebsd

I try load the native library from Mono on FreeBSD.

I have imported the method `dlopen` from library `libc.so`. The library has absolute path `/lib/libc.so.7`.

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("libc.so.7", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr dlopen(string filename, int flags);

   const int RTLD_NOW = 2;
}
```

Trying to load library

```
static void Main()
{
    IntPtr ptr = NativeMethods.dlopen("/lib/libc.so.7", NativeMethods.RTLD_NOW);
    // here ptr always equals IntPtr.Zero!!!
}
```

*Why method `dlopen` can't to load the standart library on freebsd? I can't to load the standart library so I can not  to load other libraries built me.*

In a similar way I am loading the library on ubuntu15(on ubuntu15 `libdl.so` instead `libc.so.7`) and I have always success.

Any ideas? May be it is bug in Mono?